# Confusing permissions for FOLDERID_PublicDocuments and FOLDERID_ProgramData

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, permissions, windows-xp

In trying to answer a question regarding a folder that a program can write to on any version of windows by limited users, i suggested `FOLDERID_ProgramData` and `FOLDERID_PublicDocuments`. However, it would seem that not everyone has access to this folder, despite their purpose (ostensibly) being to allow anything to write to them. Why?

Comment: Can you give a sample?  FOLDERID_PublicDocuments should be world creatable, although I can't remember off the top of my head whether users can read each other's documents.

FOLDERID_ProgramData is world readable, but not writable.

Comment: If i check the permissions of the folder backing FOLDERID_PublicDocuments using Guest (or Everyone), it shows up with no permissions. Same with ProgramData.

Comment: But Limited Users are members of the Users group, not Guest; that's pretty restricted.  I just checked this, and I was able to create and modify documents from multiple users (part of the Users group) in FOLDERID_PublicDocuments.

Comment: That's odd, because the Users group has no permissions over PublicDocuments on my machine....

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that the file owner is given full permissions on those directories, and he can then set who has access to the file.

I'll just try it out now...

...scratch that.

It seems the main set of permissions for regular users is given via the NETWORK and INTERACTIVE built-in security groups. The permissions are tied to the network location of the user (logged in locally or from the network). This is in contrast to the usual practice of granting permissions to the Users and/or Domain Users group.

This also explains why when I tried testing the effective permissions for some user, I got nothing back. (Only the administrator had explicitly defined permissions.)